# delete one word from database sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I delete one word from a MySQL database. For example, if I wanted to take a column of store names, and some end with "Inc", what query would remove the "Inc" from "Walmart Inc" for example to just leave it as Walmart?

Comment: I think you should be able to work it out from here, good luck: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. They're two different DBMSes. It's highly unlikely you're using both, so one of the tags you've used is invalid. As it's highly relevant to the question, please [edit] your post to remove the one that does not apply. The syntax and functionality between them is very different.

Comment: To modify the value stored in a column, we can use an `UPDATE` statement.  We can use an expression to derive the value to be stored. Both MySQL and SQL Server have several string functions that can perform some primitive manipulation.

Comment: @KenWhite Removed the `sql-server` tag for you.

Comment: What have you tried @Taylor? Where is this string located in relation to the rest of the string you’d like to preserve? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Do you only want to match whole words - `'Inc' -> ''`, or should partial matches be changed too - `'Incorporated' -> 'orporated'`?

Comment: @RobPaller: You didn't remove it for me. You removed it for the poster. Next time you might try letting them do it so that they learn how the tags work and how to edit their posts.

Comment: @KenWhite I thought a person with 1 reputation might not have the luxury. My bad!

Comment: @RobPaller: A user can always edit their own questions and answers, regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove 'inc' which is at  last position

```
Update tbl set column= REPLACE(column ,'Inc',' ') where RIGHT(column,3) ='Inc'
```